# onmouseover not working in chrome?

Tags: html, onmouseover

I'm trying to create a carousel in which each image has an onmouseover to change the image, using this code from W3 schools and for some reason the picture isn't changing

```
<div class="carousel-inner top-right" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <a href="#" onmouseover="document.getElementById('PhotoInfo1').src='/home/pranay/Documents/V1/V1/Pictures/PhotoInfo1.jpg';"
      onmouseout="document.getElementById('Photo1').src='/home/pranay/Documents/V1/V1/Pictures/Photo1.jpg';">
      <img src="/home/pranay/Documents/V1/V1/Pictures/Photo1.jpg" id="1" />
    </a>
  </div>
```

this is the same with only a change in image name for all items of the carousel.
Anyone know why this is happening, BTW i have already tried getElement from another post

EDIT: so i changed the id of the image there with the new code being `
which still doesnt work so i did this

```
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <a href="#" onmouseover="document.getElementById('PhotoInfo1').src='/home/pranay/Documents/V1/V1/Pictures/PhotoInfo1.jpg';"
      onmouseout="document.getElementById('Photo1').src='/home/pranay/Documents/V1/V1/Pictures/Photo1.jpg';">
      <img  src="/home/pranay/Documents/V1/V1/Pictures/Photo1.jpg" id="Photo1" />
    </a>
  </div>
```

which still doesnt work, probably because of no tag for PhotoInfo1 so i did this:

```
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <a href="#" onmouseover="document.getElementById('PhotoInfo1').src='/home/pranay/Documents/V1/V1/Pictures/PhotoInfo1.jpg';"
      onmouseout="document.getElementById('Photo1').src='/home/pranay/Documents/V1/V1/Pictures/Photo1.jpg';">
      <img  src="/home/pranay/Documents/V1/V1/Pictures/Photo1.jpg" id="Photo1" />
      <img  src="/home/pranay/Documents/V1/V1/Pictures/PhotoInfo1.jpg" id="PhotoInfo1" />
    </a>
  </div>
```

which now shows me 2 images, both photo1's one of which changes on scroll but not on mouse out and the second one doesnt change. 
I have also tried assigning an ID somewhere else for the 2nd image but this make a no change situation.

what should i do now?

I was just trying some random thing and i cam across the fact that when I use this code:

```
  <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <a href="#" onmouseover="document.getElementById('PhotoInfo1').src='/home/pranay/Documents/V1/V1/Pictures/PhotoInfo1.jpg';"
      onmouseout="document.getElementById('Photo1').src='/home/pranay/Documents/V1/V1/Pictures/Photo1.jpg';">
      <img src="/home/pranay/Documents/V1/V1/Pictures/Photo1.jpg" id="PhotoInfo1" />
    </a>
  </div>
```

i have a change in the photo from photo1 to photoinfo1 (the actual photos not the IDs) but doesnt switch back to the photo1. so what happens is that i see photo1 when page loads, after i put my mouse on it it changes to the 2nd picture but doesnt switch back to the first when i scroll off.

Why is this happening now?

Ok so this is the code that got it to work (sorta what freefaller said), but im still a little confused as to why this happened could you explain this a little further?

```
<div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
      <a href="#" onmouseover="document.getElementById('PhotoInfo1').src='/home/pranay/Documents/V1/V1/Pictures/PhotoInfo1.jpg';"
      onmouseout="document.getElementById('PhotoInfo1').src='/home/pranay/Documents/V1/V1/Pictures/Photo1.jpg';">
      <img src="/home/pranay/Documents/V1/V1/Pictures/Photo1.jpg" id="PhotoInfo1" />
    </a>
  </div>
```

Comment: Well, are there elements with ids `PhotoInfo1` and `Photo1`?

Comment: As above by @Siguza: You are trying to change the `src` attribute of element id "PhotoInfo1" and "Photo1" -- surely both of these should be "1" to match the `id="1"` in your img?

Comment: All you need to do on mouseover is target the photo in question, and change it's src, and then on mouseout change the src back to the original src.  You shouldn't need multiple images.  If that were the case why not just place image 1 and 2 in the same spot and then hide/show on mouseover and mouseout?

Comment: @AndrewIce I think changing the source is what i did in the first code, isn't it? and the problem with putting them both in the same spot is that i am using bootstrap, so they might conflict

Comment: Your HTML is invalid... you can't start an `id` with a number

Comment: @freefaller please ignore the first code, that one was a mistake i didn't notice. The problem still remains in the later codes

Comment: Then make sure you're using the correct `id`.  Your mouseover is looking for `PhotoInfo1` **element** but your mouseout is looking for `Photo1` **element**.  I think you're mistaking the name of the element and the src image name

Comment: This is where your browser development tools (F12) would come in very handy, as it will instantly tell you (in the console) any errors

Comment: @freefaller Thats right i have done that, please read the later codes

Comment: No, you haven't... writing an answer

Comment: I tried but the console only shows me the code and no errors...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're looking for different **elements** in the `document.getElementById` in your `mouseover` and `mouseout` handlers.  Your `mouseout` code can't find an element called `Photo1`.

Change your `mouseout` to use `PhotoInfo1` instead of `Photo1`.

I.e. change this...

```
<a href="#" onmouseover="document.getElementById('PhotoInfo1').src='/home/pranay/Documents/V1/V1/Pictures/PhotoInfo1.jpg';"
  onmouseout="document.getElementById('Photo1').src='/home/pranay/Documents/V1/V1/Pictures/Photo1.jpg';">
```

To this (the `^^^` is showing you the change)...

```
<a href="#" onmouseover="document.getElementById('PhotoInfo1').src='/home/pranay/Documents/V1/V1/Pictures/PhotoInfo1.jpg';"
  onmouseout="document.getElementById('PhotoInfo1').src='/home/pranay/Documents/V1/V1/Pictures/Photo1.jpg';">
                                       ^^^^^^^^^^
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you are referencing the wrong element - Your link is referring to ids 'PhotoInfo1' and 'Photo1' whereas the ID of the img you are trying to change is "1".

Try this instead:

```
<div class="carousel-inner top-right" role="listbox">
    <div class="item active">
        <a href="#" onmouseover="document.getElementById('1').src='/home/pranay/Documents/V1/V1/Pictures/PhotoInfo1.jpg';" onmouseout="document.getElementById('1').src='/home/pranay/Documents/V1/V1/Pictures/Photo1.jpg';">
        <img src="/home/pranay/Documents/V1/V1/Pictures/Photo1.jpg" id="1" />
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I figured, i'll chalk this up to a brain fart then but now when i change the id of the img tag for photo 1 nothing happens but when i add 2 img tags for both the images i see 2 images, one of them doesnt work but the second switches with the mouse over but not mouse out, ill add this to the question to make it clearer